# Android WheelView Adapter with Image

Tags: android

I had a Wheel View in my Android App. I can used it just by viewing text, but what I need is to view an images into it. I can't see any link of tutorial regarding this issue.

any thoughts will be a big help for me.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Adding images in [WheelView](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/) Control of Android .you will need to create a custom adapter by extending AbstractWheelTextAdapter and also create an row layout xml with TextView and ImageView Views.

you can see following example for adding images in WheelView :

http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/source/browse/trunk/wheel-demo/src/kankan/wheel/demo/CitiesActivity.java